# The repository jessie-backports Release does no longer have a Release file

Tags: debian

I get the following output (and error at the end) when I run `apt update` on my system:

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                 
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:7 http://fai-project.org/download stretch InRelease                                                              
Hit:8 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                          
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release              
Hit:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease          
Hit:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:14 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x stretch InRelease
Ign:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease
Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
Hit:5 https://release.memsql.com/production/debian memsql InRelease
Hit:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
Hit:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable Release  
Err:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.248.204 80]
Hit:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# These lines should work for many sites

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free

# repository that may contain newer fai packages for stretch
deb [trusted=yes] http://fai-project.org/download stretch koeln

$ grep jessie-backports /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list:# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list.save:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list.save:# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Some system information:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release:        9.8
Codename:       stretch
```

Comment: Look at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Comment: @IporSircer I updated the question to include some information from that directory as well.

Comment: I notice the use of `[trusted=yes]` on a non-https URL, rather than following the documentation on how to retrieve the correct signature key. This probably exposes you to a man-in-the-middle malware package injection anywhere in the path (so for example especially bad if it's a laptop on the move).

Answer (score 7):

A Debian version has five phases in its life cycle:

- testing: the version is in development, and has no backports or security archive
- stable: the version is now released, and a backports and security archive are created
- oldstable: the next version after this one is released. The security support is still maintained by the security team for all architectures, and the backports archive is still supported, until a year after it became oldstable.
- long-term support (LTS): a year after the release of the *next* version of Debian, the security team stops supporting this version, and the LTS team takes over. The LTS team does not support backports, and it does not support all architectures; only a limited list of architectures is supported. Additionally, not all packages are supported during the LTS phase; notably, things like webbrowsers etc are explicitly not supported (but there are many other things).
- No longer supported: the LTS phase ends 5 years after the original release of that version; at that point, the version is moved to archive.debian.org

Jessie has become oldstable on June 17th 2017, and therefore became LTS on June 17th 2018. As such, the jessie-backports repository is now dormant. It was retained for a while to allow for certain valid use cases, but the backports administrators have recently done some maintenance work, and disabled the jessie-backports repository; that is the reason you are now getting those errors.

The backports repository is meant to contain software versions that are available in the next version of Debian; i.e., jessie-backports will contain packages with versions as shipped in stretch. As such, if you have already moved to stretch as you claim to, enabling jessie-backports on your system should provide no benefit at all, and you should just stick with the stretch repository and move on from jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jessie is no longer the most recent stable release for Debian (Stretch is) I believe they no longer support jessie-backports.  It is now stretch-backports.  It is not very safe to run stretch-backports on a jessie based machine since stretch-backports are recompiled based on what's available in Stretch.  Unfortunately your options are:

1. upgrade to stretch
2. remove jessie-backports (which appears to be in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/)

Comment: Welcome, The debian release is Stretch (`lsb_release -a`), mixed  with `jessie`, `jessie-backports` , `unstable` and packagecloud jessie repo.